# Energy Cut off for Plane Wave Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

I am reading Kittel's Solid State Physics edition 8 and on pg. 172 He seems to claim that only 2 to 4 C(k-G) (coefficients of the Taylor series of the periodic potential) of the Bloch function is reasonable. How do we know this?

[image]

It seems like this is central to understanding why we can use cut off energies in many computational software like quantum expresso.

Comment: You are more likely to get an  answer to your question if you make it self contained by including the relevant background. Most people do not have a particular edition of  Kittel on hand

Comment: I see, I’ll have to fix this later.

Comment: There is also a matter modelling SE where Quantum Espresso is most relevant. It is not so small as to be 2 to 4 these days, but yes, the expansion converges very quickly in the Fourier basis. You do not know this except from actually calculating these things and seeing that they converge quickly. For example, last I heard, we still do not know why, for 2D materials using 2D specialised bases, the expansion converges slowly.

Comment: I see and this is a Fourier series of a periodic and bounded function , so it has to converge (though no constraints on speed of convergence) Thanks this was helpful. If you make this into an answer, I'll confirm it!

Comment: Well to me it looks like we are assuming that the coefficients in this Fourier series decease in magnitude. Is this reasonable and why?

Comment: My two cents is that if you ever need more than 5 terms in whatever series expansion, -  it indicates that series doesn't converge well and hence it's not the right tool for the job. In addition, there are plethora of Physics approximation problems, where taking just _first_ series term is enough (usually in linear solutions).

Comment: I see this is more of a "lets use this tool and see how far it can take us" kind of approach than a mathematically rigorous idea.

Comment: @ChristopherJacobs Well I may disappoint you, but all science is based on the idea "_let's give a shot and see where it takes_". If you want rock-solid proofs ,- you should be studying math instead. Theoretical physics is more the way you want, but still there's a lot of patching there, some guesswork, assumptions here and "gluing stuff" of otherwise monolithic reasoning peaces scattered around.

Comment: Not too disappointed, I just like to know how shaky the ground I am on is, so that during a presentation I don't try to give a "this is rigorous" (steps between math) argument when I should be giving "this is reasonable" (some assumption in a model) or a "this is working so far" (choosing a cut off energy) . Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: In practice there is always an energy cutoff, determined by the experimental conditions, duration of the experiment, approximations made, etc. E.g., it is safe to say that Kittel's analysis applies only to the situations where electron energies are low enough that they do not leave the crystal (and all the interactions and complications related to them leaving the crystal has been ignored long ago, perhaps before one began reading the book.) Then there are stronger and more explicit assumptions, like Born-Oppenheimer approximation - though may be still too basic for Kittel's level.